# unable to predict the output when we use do-while loop and write constants in while loop seperated by comma

Tags: c, do-while

```
int i=40;         //defined    
int main()
{
    do
    {
        printf("%d",i++);
    }while(5,4,3,2,1,0);  //what does this do ?

    return 0;
}

**O/P=40**
```

I am unable to figure out what the while loop does in the above code.....

I know that do while loop execute atleast once.As the `O/P=40` condition of while loop evaluates to false but iam unable to figure out how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result of expression

```
5,4,3,2,1,0
```

is `0`. So `do`-`while` is executed exactly one time.

See [Comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator).